# Ruby Remote HTTP Post

Tags: ruby

How do you do a Remote HTTP Post (request) in ruby?

Answer (score 9):

With Net::HTTP. Correct but non-working example (because Google only supports GET — sorry, I couldn't think of any open POST forms off the top of my head):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

result = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("http://google.com/search"), {"q" => "Rick Astley"})
```

[docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html)

Comment: You are posting a form to a search which takes get parameters. Google will return you an error.

Comment: That's what I said. Google actually requires GET parameters, but I couldn't think of any good examples of commonly used POST forms off the top of my head. I think it pretty clearly illustrates how you do a POST, though.

Answer (score 2):

If the server conforms to REST you should take a look at either [rest-client](http://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client/tree/master) or [ActiveResource](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activeresource).